# Google Script for Apps to Print - Cant figure what error is

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Scripts for Sheets.  I have some code I found that is very well documented and will print a spreadsheet to a PDF.  The code is posted below.  I'm getting a error on line containing:

```
 const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice").getRange("B5").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
 DriveApp.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
}
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' (line 53, file "Code.gs")

I have reviewed over and over and can't find the error.  Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Invoice Template sheets
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  // In my case is the text: 17I8-QDce0Nug7amrZeYTB3IYbGCGxvUj-XMt8uUUyvI
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XR_OQ_MmWoIZaxkr9Y0a5xf-FM1_nbWep6Ihk9o2BRw/edit#gid=1661941505");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "B7" from the "Invoice" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("PO TRACKING").getRange("A1").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  // Subject of the email message
  const subject = 'Your Report';

  // Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
 const body = "Sent via PO TRACKING from Google Form and print/email it";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XR_OQ_MmWoIZaxkr9Y0a5xf-FM1_nbWep6Ihk9o2BRw/edit#gid=1661941505/export';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape, true for portrait
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=true' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=1661941505'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
  // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid  number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
           fileName: "Invoice" + ".pdf",
           content: response.getBytes(),
           mimeType: "application/pdf"
   
  // Save the PDF to Drive. The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the Company (cell B5)
      const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice").getRange("B5").getValue().toString() +".pdf";
  DriveApp.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
}
```

Comment: If your script in your question is the actual script, in your script, `GmailApp.sendEmail(` is not closed. I thought that this might be the reason of your error message. So how about modifying `mimeType: "application/pdf"` to `mimeType: "application/pdf"}]});`?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike.   I looked at the code and it appears to have the enclosure that matches what you typed.  Its just that those brackets are on separate lines.   Would that matter?        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Invoice" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

Comment: Ahhh - i see where i was missing it. Thank you Tanaike - it works now!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.